# How do you close connections and reuse connections with urllib2?

Tags: python, urllib2

This is a two part question. The first is how do you properly close a connection with urllib2? I have seen a number of examples and I have adopted the best solution I could find. However, there appears to be a problem closing the files.

Currently I use contextlib's closing() as follows:

```
    try:
        with closing(self.opener.open(self.address, 
                                      None, 
                                      self.timeout)) as page:
            self.data = page.read()
    except:
        # bail out..
```

However, I still get "too many open files" error after a long time on OSX. I used ulimit to increase files to 2000 and above. I also set the kernel's max files up to >40,000. I should note, the object this method is located is not disposed of and it remains around for the life of the program. However, I only keep the "data" stored in the object along with the address and timeout. I don't keep the file-like object stored. I thought the problem may be references but I don't believe so because I never store a reference to the file-like object directly, only the data from read(). These objects are reused and reloaded with new data each time a thread pulls a url out of the Queue.

I only open roughly 50 connections at a time. I don't quite understand how I could run out of files. Also, when I run out of files netstat begins to crap out with malloc errors:

```
  netstat(439) malloc: *** mmap(size=18446744073708605440) failed (error code=12)
  *** error: can't allocate region
  *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
  netstat: malloc 18446744073708605396 bytes: Cannot allocate memory
```

I also can't find a way to reset the connections and get netstat back to normal without shutting down.

netstat -m

```
$ netstat -m
475/3803 mbufs in use:
    475 mbufs allocated to data
    3328 mbufs allocated to caches
407/3814 mbuf 2KB clusters in use
0/577 mbuf 4KB clusters in use
0/12 mbuf 16KB clusters in use
11242 KB allocated to network (8.3% in use)
0 requests for memory denied
0 requests for memory delayed
0 calls to drain routines
```

I am having trouble locating the error but I believe the connections are not being closed in a timely manner and I am well aware the connections are not being re-used even when connecting to a single domain (I would like that). That is the second part of the question. How can someone reuse a connection with urllib2?

I have multiple threads getting urls from a Queue and each retrieve the data via this kind of routine. If possible, I would like to reuse the connection if it has been opened by another thread. The only data shared between threads is the URL queue. I have looked at other modules but they appear to need more sharing of data than just a url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend dropping urllib2, and trying out the fantastic [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org) library.

It automatically takes care of reusing and closing connections. ([docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#keep-alive))

You might also be interested in its support for making asynchronous requests. ([docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#asynchronous-requests))

Comment: I will give this a quick shot and see if I can replace the urllib2 opener functionality with requests. The thing I am worried about is the impact with the rest of the code. I am certainly willing to give it a shot though! Thanks

Comment: I did some preliminary tests and it appears to work well. I will give it time to see if the crawler dies. I am still interested in more thoughts on the problem so I will wait before marking it solved.